# Correct way to export Ogre from Blender into jmonkeyengine?

Tags: blender, ubuntu-12.04, ogre, jmonkeyengine

I'm learning Jmonkeyengine and I'm still at about the same stage as in this question where I ask about loading models

[Enabling materials and textures for OGre 3D model in jmonkeyengine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430062/enabling-materials-and-textures-for-ogre-3d-model-in-jmonkeyengine)

Now I looked more at Blender and now at least I can get the basic usecase to work, export to Ogre 3D from Blender and then loading it in jmonkeyengine. But for more advanced models with textures, it won̈́t work.

I'm trying to load an Ogre 3D into jmonkeyengine but I think the conversion to Ogre format is not working. I can open the model in Blender but when I try to export it all I can get is a .scene file and no .mesh.xml

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

For instance opening [this mode](http://opengameart.org/content/wizard)l in Blender and exporting it to Ogre doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth: after hours of trying to figure out why JME wouldn't locate the materials, esp. when using submeshes, turned out you need to rename your material file to .material. If you use more than 1 material, append all material files to that one file.